# Can I alias a type field in Julia?

Tags: julia

For example someone define a type Bar by

```
type Bar
  v::String
end
```

I think `v` is a bad field name, and do not want to change it directly.
I want give the field an alias name, such as `value`.

I hope I can do something like `alias Bar.v, :value`, and got

```
julia> bar = Bar("the value")

julia> bar.value
"the value"
```

Can I do such thing in Julia?

Comment: The preferred way is not to directly access the field, but to define an accessor method, `value(b::Bar) = b.val`. The fieldname can be seen as part of the internal implementation of the type, and should not be of concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

The only way I can imagine you'd be able to do this is by overloading the `a.b` field access syntax (`getfield`) which you are currently not allowed to do. There is a lengthy discussion of this issue here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1974 but tldr it will probably be implemented before 1.0.

Comment: This answer is correct – this is currently not possible.

Comment: It's should be really cook if Julia has such feature!

Comment: Indeed I think there are lots of use cases where it could be cool but as @DNF pointed out defining an accessor method is often desirable for top-level usage.